# парсинг python многостраничный

Tags: python, парсер, csv

```
import numpy as np
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL='https://www.zakon.kz/news/page/3'
urls=[]
news=[]
shablons=[]
date=[]
def parse_url(URL):
  response=requests.get(URL)

  html = response.text

  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

  products = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'cat_news_item'})

  for product in products:
     href=product.find('a')
     if href:
        urls.append('https://www.zakon.kz'+href['href'])
parse_url(URL)


def parse_page(url,URL):
   news=[]
   shablons=[]
   date=[]
   response=requests.get(URL)
   response_dif=requests.get(url)

   html=response.text
   html_dif=response_dif.text

   soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
   soup_dif=BeautifulSoup(html_dif,'html.parser')

   products=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'cat_news_item'})
   products_dif=soup_dif.find_all('div',{'id': 'initial_news_story'})


   for product in products:
      for pages in products_dif:
         title=product.find('a')
         date=product.find('span')
         if title:
           date.append(date.text)
           news.append(title.text)
           shablons.append(pages.text)

   a=np.c_[date,news,shablons]
   a=a.tolist()

 with open('zakon.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as files:
     opp = csv.writer(files)
     opp.writerows(a)

 for url in urls:
     parse_page(url,URL)
```

Выдается  ошибка ,мне надо сделать так дата,заголовок,текст
помогите пж

Comment: Какая ошибка выдается?

Comment: ошибка заключается в том что при записи у меня на всех заголовок добавляется один и тот же текст и получается если у меня 134 заголовок то у меня в общем получиться  134*134  заголовок

Comment: В чем <q>этом</q>?